# how to make typescript infer the return type of a function

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have this ts function written in two different ways:

```js
    type Status = "pending_validation" | "ready_for_payment" | "paid"

    function colorStatus2(status: Status) {
        return {
            pending_validation: 'warning',
            ready_for_payment: 'inactive',
            paid: 'active',
        }[status];
    }

    function colorStatus(status: Status) {
        return status === 'pending_validation'
            ? 'warning'
            : status === 'ready_for_payment'
            ? 'inactive'
            : 'active';
    }
```

In the first case the return type is `string` but in the second it is the more specific `'warning' | 'inactive' | 'active'`

Is there a way that typescript could infer the return type for the first version without me having to specify it?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75413720/how-to-make-typescript-infer-the-return-type-of-a-function#comment133065233_75413720) @jcalz You beat me to it! https://tsplay.dev/Wo8Daw

Comment: I have edited the code in the question to be a [mre] without, I believe changing the point of the question.  Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript's heuristic type inference decides that, in object literals, properties whose values are string literals should be widened to `string` properties instead of maintaining their string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)s. This is reasonable because people often want to modify object properties:

```
const val = {
    pending_validation: 'warning',
    ready_for_payment: 'inactive',
    paid: 'active',
};
/* const val: {
    pending_validation: string;
    ready_for_payment: string;
    paid: string;
} */
val.paid = "Active";
val.pending_validation = "Attention";
```

But in your case this inference doesn't help you; you have no intention of ever modifying the properties of that object literal.  Indeed, you're thinking of it as a *constant* or *immutable* object.  Luckily TypeScript has a way to tell the compiler that you want to think of a value that way; a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const val = {
    pending_validation: 'warning',
    ready_for_payment: 'inactive',
    paid: 'active',
} as const; // <-- const assertion
/* const val: {
    readonly pending_validation: "warning";
    readonly ready_for_payment: "inactive";
    readonly paid: "active";
} */
```

Now the compiler knows that each property value will forever remain the same string literal it was when it was first created.  And therefore when you index into it, you will get those literal types you want:

```
function colorStatus(status: Status) {
    return ({
        pending_validation: 'warning',
        ready_for_payment: 'inactive',
        paid: 'active',
    } as const)[status];
}
// function colorStatus(status: Status): "warning" | "inactive" | "active"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&ssl=19&ssc=39&pln=18&pc=39#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnKBeKAiSA7AJgJa4DmA+gG7wA2h+ihA9rllAD7YBOE8+IZAM0acyYeCAC2EXMFYcc8OlgBQygMbMUwKFWoBGDFADeyqGah4ipSjToNmALigByAO7xOuYiWcAaU+bcvPxCImKS0sBOzsTwasCEFBB+AWZidNFxCUkpAL4A3MoA9ABUUBq4Wjo0ek4m5hbSVuS6dgmOUFqc3oUNQXyCwqLiUjJOXT2pFor448DdpIW5UCVFyrp6AHTp+IZYAILxiRBYhRvbTd42tPTtuHv7wMCRTCyFygJIuEfM5YzUwjgiFQAAotMCUE4gcgUABKYxTbjITxQEH1BrmSxXVq3V7RdyebwpDGBHgDULDCJjFyxI45fwktIzTJ05IM8zLeBoCpaWEAbXBMIAuktikUoJ9vnc-gDONDQYLUFCEDDYU4sASvKQ5NhadkTuxsFljipVDztLpDOi0pdrDj7Lh8R4tT52WZ+iEhuFRlEabhjfSpjsWfq8lAuX9KsBCqVI1VdHVEWTmNQQI0CNjbLiOhrnd5TkneCm0x7BmERpF1XqTb1SUXcKnphkjayC8tVkA)

Comment: excellent and very detailed explanation